# Empty set does not belong to empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Herbert in his book "Elements of set theory" on page no 3 says that

> we can form the set $ \{ \emptyset \} $ whose only member is $\emptyset $. Note that $ \{ \emptyset \} \neq  \emptyset $, because $ \emptyset \in \{ \emptyset \} $ but $\underline{ \emptyset \notin \emptyset} $·

By the last argument $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$, is he saying that **empty set** is not a member of or does not belong to **empty set**

OR

it is a typo and he wanted it to be $ \{\emptyset \} \notin \emptyset $, that **set containing empty set** is not a member of **empty set**

Comment: No typo here.${}$

Comment: Herbert? [Herbert B. Enderton?](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hbe/)

Comment: @Martin, yes, Herbert Enderton

Comment: If you have an empty lunchbox, is there an empty lunchbox inside of your empty lunchbox? No? Now replace the words "empty lunchbox" with the empty set ;)

Comment: Related: [Is {∅} a subset of {{∅}}?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/491465/121411)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course the empty set is not an element of the empty set. Nothing is an element of the empty set. That's what "empty" means.

Comment: (It is important to recognize that "nothing" plays an unusual role in English! And should not be confused with the idea of an "empty set")

Comment: @Hurkyl, but that is how I remember/understand an "empty set"

Comment: @Vikram: Then you are utterly confused. The empty set is not some essence of nothing. It is a set. Specifically, it is a set that has no elements.

Comment: Oh, I get it, thanx,

Answer (score 6):

- No set is member of the empty set
- In the usual axiomization of set theory (ZF or ZFC) no set is member of itself.

By either argument the empty set is not member of the empty set.

Maybe you were confused by the fact that the empty set trivially *contains* (as a subset, not as a member) the empty set; every set contains as a subset the empty set, and it also equally trivially contains itself as a subset. For the empty set these two cases are in fact the same, and indeed the empty set is the *unique* subset of the empty set.

Answer (score 4):

The empty set has no elements. So he is really saying that, as a particular case, the empty set is not a member of the empty set.

Answer (score 4):

The general form of the argument he makes is

> $A\ne B$ because $C\in A$ but $C\notin B$.

That, *by definition*, is how you prove that two sets are different from each other -- you prove that there is something that is member of one but not of the other.

What you're reading is simply this argument where $A$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, and $B$ and $C$ both happen to be $\varnothing$.