# In set notation, why does the meaning of A differ from the meaning of {A}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If the identity of a set depends on what the set contains, then wouldn't a set represented as A contain the same entities a set represented as {A} contains?

Comment: No. $\{A\}$ is the set whose sole element is $A$.  $A$ is a symbol for a set that could contain any number of elements.

Comment: Loosely related: [Empty set does not belong to empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/302064/121411).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see if I can make this clearer. Consider the set $\Bbb Z=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\dots\}.$ This is a set of infinitely-many numbers. However, the set $\{\Bbb Z\}$ is a set with exactly one element, and this element is not a number. It is certainly true that the element $\Bbb Z$ contains numbers, but $\{\Bbb Z\}$ only contains $\Bbb Z$ as an element. A further distinction to be made is that, while $\{\Bbb Z\}$ contains (only) $\Bbb Z,$ the set $\Bbb Z$ does *not* contain $\Bbb Z$ as an element.

Or what if we considered $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\},$ instead? The first has no elements, while the second has one, so they are certainly not the same set.

Comment: Perfectly clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As given:

$A$ is a set containing an unknown number of elements, perhaps none.

$\{A\}$ is a set containing an element which happens to be a set, and in particularly, it is a set containing $A$ as its only element. In this case, we have that $A \in \{A\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\{A\}$ is a set with only one element, the set $A$.

Comment: So say the set A contains the elements 1,2,3  - then doesn't {A} also contain 1,2,3 - so they become the same?

Comment: Sets can be elements of another set. The set $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ contains only one element, the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$. $$ \bigl\{\{1,2,3\}\bigr\}\ne\{1,2,3\}.$$

Comment: one of the questions in my text provides B={a,b}  G={{a,b},{c,2}} and asks {B}⊆G? {B} is {{a,b}}- so I answered that {B} is not a subset of G. My text says that it is. Who's wrong?

Comment: $B$ is an element of $G$. $\{B\}$ is a subset of $G$.