# Since {} is a subset of every set, it is a subset of itself? and hence {} = {{}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am bit confused with the concept of empty set here.

Since {} is a subset of every set, it is a subset of itself? and hence {} = {{}}?

Also, say A = {a}, but since {} is a subset of A, is it true that A = {a, {}}, if so, what is its cardinality?

Comment: @Andres: It seems more closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set (which was suggested as a duplicate to your suggested duplicate).

Answer (score 13):

There is a big difference between subsets and elements.

The empty set is a subset of every set, including itself. However, it is not an *element* of itself, which is what $\{\}=\{\{\}\}$ would mean.

Answer (score 4):

Being a subset of a set does not mean it is an element of a set.

The set $\{\{\}\}$ has an element, whereas $\{\}$ does not have any elements. Therefore the sets are distinct (recall that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements).

Answer (score 3):

As many other's have pointed out, the empty set is a subset of every set, it is not an element of every set.

$\{\} \subseteq A$ is always true for any set $A$.

$\{\} \in A$ is not always true.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{\}$ has no elements.  The set $\{\{\}\}$ has one element, the empty set.  Thus $\{\} \neq \{\{\}\}$

also, $A=\{a\} \neq \{a,\{\}\}$ for the very same reasons.  The right hand side set has two elements: $a$ and $\{\}$, while $A$ has only $a$ as am element.