# Is the empty set a member of itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm taking Discrete Mathematics and am a little confused on the "empty set" or "null set" defined by ∅.

I understand that ∅ is not a member of {∅} but is ∅ a member of {∅, {∅}} given that there is a null set inside this set?

Comment: $\phi$ infact is a member of $\{\phi \}$

Comment: $\emptyset$ has no elements. $\{ \emptyset \}$ has an element, namely $\emptyset$. $\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$ has two elements, namely $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set